# Getting an error below while running the cucumber feature file in IntelliJ

Tags: npm, cucumber

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\575207\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Comment: I'm getting this as well, any joy?